# How to best get the Top name from qualified paths in PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Given `$class = 'App\Something\Top'`

What is the best way to get `'Top'`? Right now Im doing

```
collect(explode('\\', $class))->last()
```

Are there any built in function for this or some Laravel helper I missed to do that a bit more slick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [`class_basename`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-class-basename) helper:

> The `class_basename` function returns the class name of the given class
>   with the class' namespace removed:
>
> ```
> $class = class_basename('Foo\Bar\Baz');
>
> // Baz
> ```